# How to add multiple table row?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

[Only show one row(last data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKwKU.png)

I did not get multiple row.There is showing only one row. How to solve this problem.

//Activity

```
public class TableViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TableLayout tableLayout;
    TableRow tableRow;
    TextView textView1, textView2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_view);
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        tableRow = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewRowTwo1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewRowTwo2);

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        students.add(new Student(1, "Mahmud"));
        students.add(new Student(2, "Saiful"));
        students.add(new Student(3, "Monir"));
        students.add(new Student(4, "Milton"));


        for (int j = 0; j< students.size(); j++) {

            textView1.setText(students.get(j).getId()+"");
            textView2.setText(students.get(j).getName());

            // TEXTVIEW
            if(textView1.getParent()!=null)
                ((ViewGroup)textView1.getParent()).removeView(textView1); // <- fix
            tableRow.addView(textView1);

            if(textView2.getParent()!=null)
                ((ViewGroup)textView2.getParent()).removeView(textView2); // <- fix
            tableRow.addView(textView2);

            if(tableRow.getParent()!=null)
                ((ViewGroup)tableRow.getParent()).removeView(tableRow); // <- fix
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

        }

        setContentView(tableLayout);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the TableRow Dynamically and whenever you put the values in tablerow you need to add that tablerow to tablelayut.

```
for (int j = 0; j< students.size(); j++) {
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    textView1.setText(students.get(j).getId()+"");
    textView2.setText(students.get(j).getName());

    // TEXTVIEW
    if(textView1.getParent()!=null)
         ((ViewGroup)textView1.getParent()).removeView(textView1); // <- fix
         tableRow.addView(textView1);
         tableLayout.addView(tableRow);


     if(textView2.getParent()!=null)
         ((ViewGroup)textView2.getParent()).removeView(textView2); // <- fix
         tableRow.addView(textView2);
         tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    if(tableRow.getParent()!=null)
        ((ViewGroup)tableRow.getParent()).removeView(tableRow); // <- fix
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks, but it can not work to me. my app has crashed after running these code.

Comment: Please paste log.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case is better for you to use a ListView. It's more easy and is designed to show a list of objects like your students.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html